# numpy mask creation broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have n-size of image (n,row,col) and n-size of floats (n,1).

what I want to do is to create mask of 0 and 1 of (row, col) size. 1's in center and 0's in edges. size of 1's is according to weights.

example

```
>>> immask = np.zeros((2,8,8))
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]

>>> multiplier = np.array([16./64,32./64])
[0.25 0.5 ]

#**insert magic here**
# expected result : 
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

is there any way to do this with broadcasting? not using loop. thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how should your weights affect the amount of 1's? Is the factor in multiplier the ratio of 1's per row/colum?

Comment: so far much like @roland-smith answer, using looping on range(n), using half of image row and col, substracted by it's ratio, slicing through like it's from (+)left/up : (-)right/down, assign them by 1. 

immask[n,(col-(multiplier[n]*col)//2):-(col-(multiplier[n]*col)//2),(row-(multiplier[n]*row)//2):-(row-(multiplier[n]*row)//2)]
(forgetting the details, but something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function does something like that:

```
import numpy as np

def make_masks(weights, rows, cols=None):
    if cols is None:
        cols = rows
    # Add two dimensions to weights
    w = np.asarray(weights)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    # Open grid of row and column coordinates
    r, c = np.ogrid[-1:1:rows * 1j, -1:1:cols * 1j]
    # Make masks where criteria is met
    return (np.abs(r) <= w) & (np.abs(c) <= w)

# Test
masks = make_masks([0.25, 0.5], 8)
# Convert type as needed
masks_f = masks.astype(np.float32)
print(masks_f)
```

Output:

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

EDIT

To make circle-shaped masks, the function could be as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def make_circle_masks(weights, rows, cols=None):
    if cols is None:
        cols = rows
    # Add two dimensions to weights
    w = np.asarray(weights)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    # Open grid of row and column coordinates
    r, c = np.ogrid[-1:1:rows * 1j, -1:1:cols * 1j]
    # Arrays with distances to centre
    d = r * r + c * c
    # Make masks where criteria is met
    return d <= w * w
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I'm looking for. can 1's be shaped to circle?

Comment: @itonia.x.i I have added a version for circle-shaped masks.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to use some kind of matrix to be applied over a picture this:

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve
```

could work for you. You could take a deeper look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.convolve) how this works.

Comment: noted. what I really want to do is to divide a image into 8x8 images, then only get center of image according to it's weights/percents, so it looks like images but dotted-like and vary on radius of the dot-like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [3]: immask = np.zeros((2,8,8))

In [6]: immask[0, 3:5, 3:5] = 1                                                                          

In [7]: immask[1, 2:6, 2:6] = 1                                                                          

In [8]: immask                                                                                           
Out[8]: 
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: nice, I can use loop on 'n' (i.e. 2), and using it's negative instead
immask[0, 3:-3, 3:-3] = 1.
it is easy to read in loop but it will take long since I have many 'n'.